# What is the right to dynamically add these elements in DOM for such cases?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website that has a list as shown in picture. Now, there are two ways to add these list items for each user.

One (see ex. 1) is by using pure JavaCript and jQuery.
The other (see ex. 2) is using string concatenation.

For each list item, I have to run a for loop. So I think there might be at least **2 issues** related to speed, performance and ease.

**First**, I need to choose one of them considering speed and performance.
**Second**, If you see Example **1**, I have "pick and drop pick and drop each smallest element and I've to keep in mind who is parent and who is child. Further, I have to carefully add the **classes** and **attributes** to correct parent. But in Example **2**, the HTML is in front of you. So I don't need to keep in mind such things much.

So is this 'ease' thing in just my mind or am I really doing something wrong?

**Example 1:** JavaScript / jQuery

```
function createListItem(todo, count) {
li = '';
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.id = "user" + count + " user_" + todo.userid;
li.className = "user user_" + todo.userid;

var item = document.createElement('div');
item.className = 'item';


var inner = document.createElement('div');
inner.className = 'inner';
inner.style.cssText = 'height:86px';

var item_specific = document.createElement('div');
item_specific.className = 'item-specific2 item-specific';
/*battery*/
var device_battery = document.createElement('span');
device_battery.id = 'device_battery' + count;
device_battery.className = 'device_battery';
device_battery.title = 'Device Battery Status';
fa_bolt = document.createElement('i');
fa_bolt.className = 'fa ' + ' ' + todo.bolt;
fa_bolt.style.cssText = 'color: white !important;opacity: 1 !important;';
battery_percent = document.createElement('i');
battery_percent.className = 'fa ' + todo.battery_life + '';
device_battery.append(fa_bolt)
device_battery.append(battery_percent)
device_battery.append(todo.battery + '%')
/*Device status*/
var device_status = document.createElement('span');
device_status.id = 'device_status' + count;
device_status.className = 'device_status';
device_status.title = 'Device Battery Status';
fa_bolt = document.createElement('i');
fa_bolt.className = 'fa ' + todo.circleforonline;
device_status.append(fa_bolt)
device_status.append(todo.status)
/*Employee status*/
var employee_status = document.createElement('span');
employee_status.id = 'employee_status' + count;
employee_status.className = 'employee_status';
employee_status.title = 'Internet & GPS Status';
fa_bolt = document.createElement('i');
fa_bolt.className = 'fa ' + todo.circleforcharging;
employee_status.append(fa_bolt)
employee_status.append(todo.is_charging)
/*Employee Image*/
mCS_img_loaded = document.createElement('IMG')
mCS_img_loaded.className = 'mCS_img_loaded';
mCS_img_loaded.id = 'img_src' + count + '';
mCS_img_loaded.style.cssText = 'float: left';
mCS_img_loaded.src = todo.img_path;
$("img").error(function () {
//console.log('image')
//$(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "assets/img/items/real-estate/6.jpg");
})
/*Employee name*/
delivery_boy_name = document.createElement('div');
delivery_boy_name.className = 'delivery_boy_name dely_boy pan-to-marker';
delivery_boy_name.setAttribute("data-wholedata", count)
delivery_boy_name.setAttribute("data-userid", todo.userid)
delivery_boy_name.setAttribute("data-marker-lat", todo.lang)
delivery_boy_name.setAttribute("data-marker-lng", todo.lng)
delivery_boy_name.setAttribute("data-marker-index", count)
delivery_boy_name.addEventListener("click", view_orders_click);
h3_name = document.createElement('h3');
h3_name.append(todo.fname + ' ' + todo.lname)
delivery_boy_name.append(h3_name)
/*Employee Estimate time*/
estimate = document.createElement('div')
estimate_text = document.createElement('div')
estimate_text.style.cssText = 'float: left;';
estimate_text.id = 'eta_' + todo.userid + '';
estimate.className = 'row eta estimate';
estimate.setAttribute("data-userid", todo.userid)
estimate.addEventListener("click", view_estimate_click);
estimate_div = document.createElement('div')
estimate_div.style.cssText = 'float: left;background: #0f9595;font-size: 14px;color: #fff;margin-left: 15px;padding: 0 4px;width:20px;border-radius: 50%;margin-right: 5px;';
fa_bolt = document.createElement('i');
fa_bolt.className = 'fa fa-refresh';
estimate_text.append('ETA')
estimate_div.append(fa_bolt)
estimate.append(estimate_div)
estimate.append(estimate_text)
/*Assign button*/
assign_resposnive = document.createElement('div')
assign_resposnive.className = 'price price2 assign_resposnive'
assign_resposnive.setAttribute("data-mobile", todo.mobile)
assign_resposnive.setAttribute("data-userid", todo.userid)
anchor_order = document.createElement('a')
anchor_order.className = 'assign_order'
anchor_order.setAttribute("href", '#assign_order')
anchor_order.setAttribute("data-toggle", 'toggle')
anchor_order.setAttribute("data-mobile", todo.mobile)
anchor_order.setAttribute("data-userid", todo.userid)
anchor_order.style.cssText = 'color:white;font-size: 10px;';
assign_resposnive.append(anchor_order)
assign_resposnive.addEventListener("click", assign_button_click);
anchor_order.append('ASSIGN')
/*View order button*/
view_orders = document.createElement('div')
view_orders.className = 'view_orders pan-to-marker'
view_orders.setAttribute("data-wholedata", count)
view_orders.setAttribute("data-userid", todo.userid)
view_orders.setAttribute("data-marker-lat", todo.lang)
view_orders.setAttribute("data-marker-lng", todo.lng)
view_orders.setAttribute("data-marker-index", count)
get_assigned_data = JSON.search(store.getAll().get_assigned_data, '//*[dbid="' + todo.userid + '" and order_status="A"]');
view_orders.addEventListener("click", view_orders_click);
view_orders.append('VIEW ORDERS(' + (get_assigned_data).length + ')')
/*view geofence button*/

view_geofence = document.createElement('div')
view_geofence.className = 'view_orders  view_geofence_ '
view_geofence.setAttribute("data-fname", todo.fname)
view_geofence.setAttribute("data-geo_latitude", todo.geo_latitude)
view_geofence.setAttribute("data-geo_longitude", todo.geo_longitude)
view_geofence.setAttribute("data-geo_radius", todo.geo_radius)
view_geofence.setAttribute("data-wholedata", count)
view_geofence.setAttribute("data-userid", todo.userid)
view_geofence.setAttribute("data-marker-lat", todo.lang)
view_geofence.setAttribute("data-marker-lng", todo.lng)
view_geofence.setAttribute("data-marker-index", count)
view_geofence.addEventListener("click", view_geofence_click);
view_geofence.append('VIEW GEOFENCE')

item_specific.append(device_battery)
item_specific.append(device_status)
item_specific.append(employee_status)
inner.append(item_specific)
inner.append(mCS_img_loaded)
inner.append(delivery_boy_name)
inner.append(assign_resposnive)
inner.append(view_orders)
if (todo.geo_latitude && todo.geo_longitude && todo.geo_radius) {
inner.append(view_geofence)
}
li.append(item)
item.append(inner)
item.append(estimate)

return li;
}
```

**Example 2: Concatenation**

```
dataHtml += '<li id="' + i + '"><div class="item" id="' + i + '"><div class="inner" style="height:86px"><div class="item-specific2 item-specific"><span title="Device Battery Status" id="device_battery' + i + '" class="device_battery"><i class="fa ' + bolt + '" style="color: white !important;opacity: 1 !important;"></i><i class="fa ' + battery_life + '"></i>' + path_map[i]['battery'] + '%</span><span class="device_status" id="device_status' + i + '" title="Internet & GPS Status"><i class="' + circleforonline + '"></i>' + status + '</span><span class="employee_status" id="employee_status' + i + '" title="Internet & GPS Status"><i class="' + circleforcharging + '"></i>' + is_charging + '</span></div><img class="mCS_img_loaded" id="img_src' + i + '" style="float:left" src="' + imgUrl + '" alt=""><a  data-target="" class=" " style=""  ><div class="delivery_boy_name dely_boy pan-to-marker" data-wholedata="' + i + '" data-userID=' + path_map[i]['userid'] + '  data-marker-lat="' + path_map[i]['lang'] + '" data-marker-lng="' + path_map[i]['lng'] + '" data-userID=' + path_map[i]['userid'] + '   data-marker-index="' + i + '"><h3>' + path_map[i]['fname'] + ' ' + path_map[i]['lname'] + '</h3></div></a><div data-mobile="' + path_map[i]['mobile'] + '" data-userid="' + path_map[i]['userid'] + '" class="price price2 assign_resposnive" style=""><a href="#assign_order" class="assign_order" style="color:white;font-size: 11px;" data-toggle="modal" data-mobile=' + path_map[i]['mobile'] + ' data-userid="' + path_map[i]['userid'] + '" data-target="" >ASSIGN </a></div><div class="view_orders pan-to-marker" data-wholedata="' + i + '" data-userID=' + path_map[i]['userid'] + '  data-marker-lat="' + path_map[i]['lang'] + '" data-marker-lng="' + path_map[i]['lng'] + '" data-userID=' + path_map[i]['userid'] + '   data-marker-index="' + i + '">VIEW ORDERS(' + (get_assigned_data).length + ')</div>' + geofence + '<div class="arrow_img"></div></div><div class="row eta estimate" data-userID=' + path_map[i]['userid'] + ' style=""><div style="float: left;background: #0f9595;font-size: 14px;color: #fff;margin-left: 15px;padding: 0 4px;width:20px;border-radius: 50%;margin-right: 5px;"><i  class="fa fa-refresh " aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:13px;"></i></div><div style="float:left" id="eta_' + path_map[i]['userid'] + '">ETA</div></div><div class="wrapper expandable-content show-0 collapsed " id="wrapper_id' + i + '"><a href="#assign_order"  style="" data-toggle="modal" data-wholedata="' + i + '" data-userID=' + path_map[i]['userid'] + '  data-marker-lat="' + path_map[i]['lang'] + '" data-marker-lng="' + path_map[i]['lng'] + '"   data-marker-index="' + i + '"  data-target="" class="pan-to-marker " style="" ></a><table><tr><td class="td-35-icon"><div class="fa fa-phone"></div></td><td class="td-35">' + path_map[i]['mobile'] + '</td></tr><tr style="border-left: 1px solid #000;"><td class="fa fa-map-marker td-80-icon" style="padding-top:34px"></td><td class="td-80"><div id="addrss' + i + '"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="td-35-icon"> <div class="fa fa-clock-o" ></td><td  class="td-35"> </td></tr></table></div></div></li>';
```

**Output:**

[image]

NOTE: Example 2 doesn't create the same text and buttons as Example 1. Basically the structure is same. You should consider them same while answering.

Comment: *"1) is by using pure JavaCript and jQuery."* - I don't see any jQuery methods in your code except for `$("img").error`. If you used jQuery to create the new elements you could make the first code block a whole lot neater because you can add multiple attributes to elements at the same time. Having said that, I think version 2 would be OK if you included some line breaks to make the code readable.

Comment: Since you say you are using jQuery, have you considered chaining to make the code more maintainable?

Comment: @nnnnnn `append` is jQuery method, no? Secondly, could you please provide some reference for what you're saying like multiple attributes?

Comment: @Forty3 chaining like how? Any reference for example?

Comment: jQuery does have an `.append()` method, but you're trying to call that on a non-jQuery object so that won't work.

Comment: But it's working fine on my website @nnnnnn :D

Comment: I misspoke. Let me clarify: you are using the standard DOM `.append()` method, not the jQuery `.append()` method. Regarding adding multiple attributes, [jQuery's `.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes) lets you pass an object listing all of the required attributes. Or the [`$()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) lets you pass attributes in an object at the same time as you create the new element.

Comment: Oh okay. So you're saying about multiple attributes at same time. Which should I use then concatenate or jQuery?

Comment: @VikasKumar - chaining would be where you create an element and then call multiple methods on against it: `var item_specific = $("<DIV></DIV>").addClass("item-specific2 item-specific").append($("<SPAN></SPAN>").attr("id", 'device_battery' + count).addClass("device_battery").attr("title", 'Device Batter Status')).append($("<I></I>").addClass('fa ' + ' ' + todo.bolt).css({"color":"white","opacity","1 !important"));` and so on.

Comment: I should also point out that via chaining, you can embed newlines before the `.(...)` calls to make things look a bit cleaner.

Comment: But it will also look messed when I will write the whole complete code for a single list item.

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't see any site saying `append()` is a JavaScript DOM method. It's only in jQuery.

Comment: [Look harder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) (admittedly it's not in all browsers). If it *was* only in jQuery your code would give an error because you're calling `.append()` directly on DOM elements.

Comment: Okay. Could you please give a link where I can read all about DOM methods, especially by which I can append classnames and attributes, like `appendChild()`,  `createTextNode()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn could you tell why you reply only alternate comments?

Comment: The MDN website that I linked to in my previous comment has pretty thorough documentation for all DOM methods and for JS in general. Alternate comments?  I'm not logged in all day so I don't see your comments in real time.

Comment: :P Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a appreciable HTML chunk to repeat and to fill with infos you have in an array of objects.

The two options you've tried are hard to read... And so to maintain.

Here is how I would do it, using jQuery.
So first, this assumes an array of object looking like this:

```
var path_map=[
  {
    battery:"79",
    userid:9876,
    lang:40.730610,
    lng:-73.935242,
    fname:"John",
    lname:"Doh",
    mobile:"555-555-5555",
    bolt:"fa-bolt",
    battery_life:"fa-battery-three-quarters green",
    circleforonline:"fa-circle green",
    status:"online",
    circleforcharging:"fa-circle orange",
    is_charging:"charging"
  },{
    battery:"50",
    userid:5656,
    lang:40.730610,
    lng:-73.935242,
    fname:"Johnny",
    lname:"Deeh",
    mobile:"555-555-4444",
    bolt:"fa-bolt",
    battery_life:"fa-battery-half orange",
    circleforonline:"fa-circle green",
    status:"online",
    circleforcharging:"fa-circle orange",
    is_charging:"charging"
  },{
    battery:"10",
    userid:5656,
    lang:40.730610,
    lng:-73.935242,
    fname:"Suzy",
    lname:"Sheer",
    mobile:"555-555-7777",
    bolt:"fa-bolt",
    battery_life:"fa-battery-quarter red",
    circleforonline:"fa-circle green",
    status:"online",
    circleforcharging:"fa-circle orange",
    is_charging:"charging"
  }
];
```

**Now I would type ONE `li` in the body of my HTML document** and set it hidden, using the `id`.
Let's call it `#clone`... Because this "empty" `li` will never be shown.
It is a "template" to be cloned in the `for` loop which will go through your objects.

In the loop, I would just insert the infos where they have to be.
And then, I would append this cloned `li` to the `ul`.
The changed `id` will make it visible.

The code would look like this *(much more readable)*:

```
for(i=0;i<path_map.length;i++){
  var myClone = $("#clone").clone();

  myClone.attr("id",i);

  myClone.find(".device_battery").append(path_map[i]["battery"]+"%");
  myClone.find(".device_battery").find("i").eq(0).addClass(path_map[i]["bolt"]);
  myClone.find(".device_battery").find("i").eq(1).addClass(path_map[i]["battery_life"]);
  myClone.find(".device_status").append(path_map[i]["status"]);
  myClone.find(".device_status").find("i").addClass(path_map[i]["circleforonline"]);
  myClone.find(".employee_status").append(path_map[i]["is_charging"]);
  myClone.find(".employee_status").find("i").addClass(path_map[i]["circleforcharging"]);
  myClone.find(".employee_name").append(path_map[i]["fname"]+" "+path_map[i]["lname"]);
  myClone.find(".employee_mobile").append(path_map[i]["mobile"]);

  $("ul").append(myClone);
}
```

**So in short,** I would separate the "simple" HTML from the code used to insert the data into it.

Have a look at the below snippet and/or this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vZpQJb).

```js
var path_map=[
  {
    battery:"79",
    userid:9876,
    lang:40.730610,
    lng:-73.935242,
    fname:"John",
    lname:"Doh",
    mobile:"555-555-5555",
    bolt:"fa-bolt",
    battery_life:"fa-battery-three-quarters green",
    circleforonline:"fa-circle green",
    status:"online",
    circleforcharging:"fa-circle orange",
    is_charging:"charging"
  },{
    battery:"50",
    userid:5656,
    lang:40.730610,
    lng:-73.935242,
    fname:"Johnny",
    lname:"Deeh",
    mobile:"555-555-4444",
    bolt:"fa-bolt",
    battery_life:"fa-battery-half orange",
    circleforonline:"fa-circle green",
    status:"online",
    circleforcharging:"fa-circle orange",
    is_charging:"charging"
  },{
    battery:"10",
    userid:5656,
    lang:40.730610,
    lng:-73.935242,
    fname:"Suzy",
    lname:"Sheer",
    mobile:"555-555-7777",
    bolt:"fa-bolt",
    battery_life:"fa-battery-quarter red",
    circleforonline:"fa-circle green",
    status:"online",
    circleforcharging:"fa-circle orange",
    is_charging:"charging"
  }
];

for(i=0;i<path_map.length;i++){
  var myClone = $("#clone").clone();

  myClone.attr("id",i);

  myClone.find(".device_battery").append(path_map[i]["battery"]+"%");
  myClone.find(".device_battery").find("i").eq(0).addClass(path_map[i]["bolt"]);
  myClone.find(".device_battery").find("i").eq(1).addClass(path_map[i]["battery_life"]);
  myClone.find(".device_status").append(path_map[i]["status"]);
  myClone.find(".device_status").find("i").addClass(path_map[i]["circleforonline"]);
  myClone.find(".employee_status").append(path_map[i]["is_charging"]);
  myClone.find(".employee_status").find("i").addClass(path_map[i]["circleforcharging"]);
  myClone.find(".employee_name").append(path_map[i]["fname"]+" "+path_map[i]["lname"]);
  myClone.find(".employee_mobile").append(path_map[i]["mobile"]);

  $("ul").append(myClone);
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.green{
  color:green;
}
.orange{
  color:orange;
}
.red{
  color:red;
}
#clone{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li id="clone">
    <div class="item" id="123123">
      <div class="inner" style="height:86px">
        <div class="item-specific2 item-specific">
          <span title="Device Battery Status" id="device_battery123123" class="device_battery">
            <i class="fa"></i>
            <i class="fa"></i>
          </span>
          <span class="device_status" id="device_status123123" title="Internet & GPS Status">
            <i class="fa"></i>
          </span>
          <span class="employee_status" id="employee_status123123" title="Internet & GPS Status">
            <i class="fa"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="employee_name"></div>
        <div class="employee_mobile"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

By the way, It would be a good idea to have a specific `class` for each "placeholder" would spare all the extra `.find()` and `.eq()`. I just made this example looking like your HTML.